# What is the best way to setup a heartbeat agent for failover between two VMs?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, failover, heartbeat

I have two VMs in VirtualBox that use NAT for their network adapters. They are both getting the same IP address, so I will need to reconfigure that; but knowing that, is it possible to set up a heartbeat agent to failover an apache server if one of the two VMs go down?

The way I pictured it would be that the webserver would be able to be accessed externally via :80. No matter what VM was running, I would be able to access the website at that IP/port since failover would be setup.

I'm running into trouble setting up IPs when the network adapters are set to NAT, and people have told me that I shouldn't be setting the IPs in this configuration. So what should I do to achieve what I'm looking for? Is it even feasible?

Comment: You shouldn't be using VirtualBox for anything important, either.

Comment: The systems aren't actually important, I just wanted to see if I could set up a failover like this.

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach is sticking the web servers behind a load balancer and leaving the services running on both. You setup both Active/Passive and Active/Active depending on your requirements.

If you can't afford, or don't want to buy physical load balancers, then you can achieve what you are requesting by:

- setting up something like [piranha](http://sourceware.org/piranha/), assuming you are running linux. It is possible to use the same machines as those running web server for this.
- or you can cluster them with [RHCS](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Cluster_Suite_Overview/s1-rhcs-intro-CSO.html), again, assuming you are running linux.

*The possibilities are endless.*

Comment: `lvs` would be another LB solution. But how to make these LBs HA? So active/passive is normally easier, if active/active is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You need a logical service-IP for your webservice.

That being done your resource-group consists of two items:

- logical IP
- httpd

Make sure you have enough heartbeat-lines so the cluster "knows" for sure that the other node is down before failing over.